# PasteSpecial is giving me a run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have so far is able to select the files, and copies some of them to the Sheet2.

When I run the code, It errors out a:
`With xlBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(xlRow, xlColm) .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats....`

There are merged cells in the files, but I need them as they are reports, and I'm simply trying to compile them into a nice PDF. I also need the format of the reports to stay the same/similar.

```vb
Sub Compile_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim xlBook, srcBook As Workbook
    Dim fileSlct As FileDialog
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xlRow, lstRow, xlColm, lstColm As Long
    Dim fileIdx, cntSheet As Integer
   
    Set xlBook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet2"
    '    On Error GoTo error2

    '   On Error GoTo error
    
    Set fileSlct = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)            'Allows user to select the files/reports
    With fileSlct
        .AllowMultiSelect = True                                              'Allows for many file to be selected
        .Title = "Select target files:"
        .ButtonName = "Open"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb; *.xls; *.xlw"
        .Show
    End With
    
    If fileSlct.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No file found that match.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For fileIdx = 1 To fileSlct.SelectedItems.Count                            'Loops through each of the selected items, and copies them to workbook
        Set srcBook = Workbooks.Open(fileSlct.SelectedItems(fileIdx))
        Set xlSheet = srcBook.ActiveSheet
        xlRow = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1     'xlRow+colm are the last used values in the xlBook(Dest)
        xlColm = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For Each xlSheet In srcBook.Sheets
            cntSheet = cntSheet + 1
            If xlSheet.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
              xlSheet.Activate
              lstRow = xlSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                    'lstRow+Colm are the last used values in the scrBook
              lstColm = xlSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
              xlSheet.UsedRange.Copy                               'Copies the conent from scrBook to Sheet
              With xlBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(xlRow, xlColm)
                  .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats                        'Pastes the formats of the srcBooks
                  .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                  .PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
              End With
              xlRow = xlRow + 1
            End If
        Next xlSheet
        srcBook.Close False
    Next fileIdx
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF  'Going to be used to convert the newly popluated sheet to PDF. Still need to fiure that out :?
    
    '    Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Refer to folder to view PDF. " & vbCrLf & _
    fileSlct.SelectedItems.Count & " Reports have been complied.", vbInformation 'All done!
    
    'error:
       '  MsgBox "Error Number " & Err.Number & " " & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical
     'error2:
     '   Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
     '  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet2"
      ' Resume Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Highly suggest you get rid of all merged cells if possible, and instead use Alignment > Center Across Selection. Merged cells are nothing but a headache.

Comment: I really wish I could. These reports are generated from another database and I don't have control over the formatting they do.

Comment: Try pasting all, then copying the newly pasted data, then pasting as values on top of itself.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: First try doing it manually to see if it even works.

Comment: The paste all works fine on it's own to get all the data. I did try to use just it in macro, but it's still erroring out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of operations makes a difference.
Try this approach:

```
Sub example()
    Set Rng = Sheets(1).Range("M7:Q13")
    
    With Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count)
        .UnMerge ' umerge destination area first 
        Rng.Copy ' after that copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' then paste values
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments 'and other pastes
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Would this work for different sheets as well? @Алексей Р

Comment: Thanks @Алексей Р It works much better now, though some data appears to be missing.

Comment: @kaligirl I think you need to double-check the paste coordinates and copy and paste area sizes for your situation - data can overwrite each other if you repeatedly paste into the same sheet

Comment: Ok good to know. Thank you for the help! I have been stuck on this part of a while.

Comment: I managed to figure out why the tables are not 'stacking' and fixed it. but I have another issue; some tables dont seem to be pasting properly. some of them work fine. I also noticed that there are images under one. Could this be causing an error?

Comment: In my opinion, no. I could not reproduce the error related to copying a range containing images.