# How to copy values from sheets to another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge several sheets into one.

**Configuration**

DataSheet1 : First sheet
DataSheet2 : Second sheet
ConsolidatedSheet : Consolidated sheet

**Code**

```
Set consolidatedSheet = Worksheets("ConsolidatedSheet")
consolidatedSheet.Activate

startRow = 2
startCol = 1

Worksheets("DataSheet1").Activate
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, startCol).End(xlUp).row
lastCol = Cells(startRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(startRow, startCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy _
consolidatedSheet.Range("A" & consolidatedSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1)

Worksheets("DataSheet2").Activate
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, startCol).End(xlUp).row
lastCol = Cells(startRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(startRow, startCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy _
consolidatedSheet.Range("A" & consolidatedSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1)
```

**Issue**

Two arrays are created in the consolidated sheet. It means I can't sort on the consolidated sheet.

How do I copy data as values instead of arrays?

Comment: Have you tried using `Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`?

Comment: with this code ? `consolidatedSheet.Range("A" & consolidatedSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`. Because I'm facing following issue : Compile error, Expected : end of statement`

Comment: First you must do Range.Copy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322157/pastespecial-is-giving-me-a-run-time-error-1004/67322990#67322990

Comment: It is done on the row : `Range(Cells(startRow, startCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy`

Comment: And what you called an array - did you mean `formula array` or a `smart table`?

Comment: By array I mean, `formula array` yes. `Filter` function is used automatically.

Comment: It is convenient to use `rng.CurrentArray` to define the area of `formula arrays`, where rng is any cell inside the array. Also for `smart table` - `rng.ListObject.DataBodyRange`, for `range` - `rng.CurrentRegion`. This can greatly simplify the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231992/discussion-between---and-royce).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not able to access to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub consSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With Worksheets("ConsolidatedSheet")
        .Cells.Delete   ' clear the assignment sheet first
        For Each ws In Sheets(Array("DataSheet1", "DataSheet2"))
            ws.Cells(2, 1).CurrentArray.Copy
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Next ws
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' "clears" the clipboard
End Sub
```

**Edit2:** (not copy headers from DataSheet1 and DataSheet2 and keep existing header in ConsolidatedSheet)

```
Sub consSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With Worksheets("ConsolidatedSheet")
        .Rows("2:" & .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count).Delete ' clear (without header in Row 1) the assignment sheet first
        
        For Each ws In Sheets(Array("DataSheet1", "DataSheet2"))
            Set Rng = ws.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
            Set Rng = Intersect(Rng, Rng.Offset(1)) ' eliminate headers
            
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Copy
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next ws
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' "clears" the clipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I'm facing an error `No Cells were found` on the row `ws.Cells(2, 1).CurrentArray.Copy`

Comment: @Royce you previously wrote: "By array I mean, formula array yes". Given the error, it appears that you don't have an array formula (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#:~:text=An%20array%20formula%20is%20a,more%20items%20in%20an%20array.&text=Beginning%20with%20the%20September%202018,or%20across%20into%20neighboring%20cells.) in this location. You can use another way to select the area

Comment: ... for example, `ws.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy`

Comment: Thank you for you feedback. It is working fine. The only remaining point is headers. This code copying headers from `DataSheet1` and `DataSheet2` and remove header in `ConsolidatedSheet`. It is possible to not copy headers from `DataSheet1` and `DataSheet2` and keep existing header in `ConsolidatedSheet` ?

Comment: @Royce possible, see Edit2 in the solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by it creating arrays, and I don't think that code is actually the code using as it's not doing what you describe.

But here's something that does what your intending.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    
    Dim cSht As Worksheet
    Set cSht = Worksheets("ConsolidatedSheet")
    
    Dim StartRow As Integer, StartCol As Integer
    StartRow = 1
    StartCol = 1
    
    'Split out to a sub and don't need to repeat self
    Call ConsolidateData(cSht, "DataSheet1", StartRow, StartCol, True)
    Call ConsolidateData(cSht, "DataSheet2", StartRow, StartCol)
    
End Sub

Private Sub ConsolidateData(cSht As Worksheet, FromSheet As String, StartRow As Integer, StartCol As Integer, Optional IncludeHeader As Boolean)
    
    Dim FromRow As Integer
    If IncludeHeader Then
        FromRow = StartRow
    Else
        FromRow = StartRow + 1
    End If
    
    With Worksheets(FromSheet)
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartCol).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol = .Cells(StartRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        'Just transfering value is faster then copy, but doesn't bring formatting
        cSht.Cells(cSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(lastrow - FromRow, lastcol - StartCol).Value2 = .Range(.Cells(FromRow, StartCol), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Value2
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exaclty what I'm looking for. However, the last column and the last row are not copied. Any idea why ? `+1` on `lastcol` fixed a part of the problem. However, `+1` on `lastrow` will works only for the last sheet copied... The last row of previous sheet is replaced by the first row of the next sheet copied.